# Need Visa during Paris layover?

Tags: visas, paris

I am a U.S. citizen and will be laying over in Paris for 23 hours.  I want to go into Paris and look around.  Will I need to have a visa or something to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: The short answer is that US citizens can visit Schengen countries (which include France) without a visa.